# Is there some security restriction preventing apache2 from listening on a high port?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, virtual-host

I have configured an Apache2 virtual host to listen on a port above port 80, 8011 in this case.

`apachectl configtest`  returns no error in regards on the  usage of the high port, yet netstat indicates the port is not in use and telneting to the IP address shows it is not in use. The Apache log generates no logs. Here is the virtual host configuration. As far as I can tell using port 8011 should work as there is nothing listening on it, yet Apache2 seems to ignore it completely. Could there be some `apparmor` or `SELinux` configuration stopping it? Is the virtual host  failing to load? If it is failing then apache2 is not  logging an error.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.56.52:8011>
        ServerName lazrepos.ho.local
        ServerAlias util01.lazrepos.ho.local lazrepos.br.local util01.lazrepos.br.local util01.lazrepos.local lazvbox.local
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/lazrepos/repos/svn

        DirectoryIndex index.html

        <Directory />
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory  /home/lazrepos/repos/cgi/viewvc/bin/cgi/ >
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
                Options +ExecCGI
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /viewvc /home/lazrepos/repos/cgi/viewvc/bin/cgi/viewvc.cgi
        ScriptAlias /query /home/lazrepos/repos/cgi/viewvc/bin/cgi/query.cgi

        ErrorLog /home/lazrepos/sites/lazrepos/www/logs/apache2/error.log
        CustomLog /home/lazrepos/sites/lazrepos/www/logs/apache2/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        LoadModule dav_module         modules/mod_dav.so
        LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so

        <Location /lazrepos/svn>
          DAV svn
          SVNParentPath /home/lazrepos/repos/svn/fpc_laz
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Add to `ports.conf` the line `Listen 8011` and restart Apache

Comment: It turns out to be the absence of  a Listen XXXX option in `ports.conf` or in the relevant virtual hosts file.

Comment: Txs for the feedback, I am mobile, will write an answer later on at the computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the absence of a `Listen XXXX` option in ports.conf or in the relevant virtual host file. Adding `Listen 8011` to `ports.conf` or adding it to the top of the virtual host file fixed the problem.

What I found surprising that the error log file for both the main server and the virtual host did not warn that the 8011 in `<VirtualHost 192.168.56.52:8011>` did not have a matching `Listen` command. Perhaps it requires additional options in some of the configuration files or the run scripts

Comment: do it at ports.conf as it is more standard

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It is on  my personal server and I like to keep settings closest to the place where they are used. In a standard working environment I would use ports.conf

Answer (score 2):

If apache has problems loading config, often you'll see the errors in the errorlog file, `/home/lazrepos/sites/lazrepos/www/logs/apache2/error.log`.

- Is there a firewall on the machine/network that would prevent a telnet?
- Were you telnetting locally to the address?
- Are you telling Apache to read the configuration file, presumably in `/home/lazrepos` somewhere, with the `f` switch?